# Does isolation in Moana reflect a real island?

Tags: historical-accuracy, moana

I know polynesians went through a period where they generally didn't discover new islands. I've heard the movie *Moana* was meant to reflect the period when they stopped exploring. But this is a lot different than islands losing contact with other islands they are already aware of.

So were there islands in Polynesia that lost contact with the rest of society, and then regained contact and started exploring again?